# raw_input() with With White Spaces in Between the Inputs in Python 2

Tags: python

I am solving problems on [Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com) in Python 2. I want take input of two numbers which are given as below

```
5 2
```

I want to store them in two different variables. How can I do that? (Inputs are given as standard inputs)

For inputs given in new lines, I can use `raw_input()`.

I have tried using `strip()`, but it seems to be removing only leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input_arr = raw_input('input here :').split(' ')
```

split will return an array of of the original string splitted at the regex passed in parameters

```
'H ell o'.split(' ') # ---> ['H', 'ell', 'o']

'H ell o'.split('e') # ---> ['H ', 'll o']

'H# ell# o'.split('#') # ---> ['H', ' ell', ' o']
```

Comment: `.split()` is more robust than `.split(' ')` here -- just in case the user should type `5  2` with two spaces between the numbers, `split` w/o arguments will still work fine, but with `' '` as an argument it will also produce an empty string in the middle.

Comment: @AlexMartelli This is cool , it will always split at spaces even if the spaces are in different length (i.e '5 twospaces 2 one space 3') ?  however it is not needed in competitions as the input is always in the same format

Answer (score 1):

Use split:

```
a,b = raw_input().split()

In [3]: a,b = raw_input().split()
5 2

In [4]: a
Out[4]: '5'

In [5]: b
Out[5]: '2'
```